# Why are some of my nodes different to nodes in tutorials I watch?

Tags: node-editor

I watch tutorials for references from time to time and I noticed some of the nodes in my version Blender 2.81 are different from tutorials on Youtube. I don't see Voronoi texture has no Fac socket and I cannot check volumetric in EVEEE or Cycle. I do have the Blender 2.81. I believe I am not getting the benefits they were meant to create.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The Voronoi node did change slightly between 2.8 and 2.81. But all functionality was kept and some added. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello :) I didn't see many changes from 2.8 to 2.81 probably some nodes that I ran into. I switched around i think it's just how they labeled it, color seems to be working as factor. I'm trying to get pattern of shades on cube and some of them has to bit glossy and solid metal. thanks for your help appreciate it.